# Get Product Codes of C++ 2008 Installed from registry using Powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-c++-2008

I am trying to get the product codes of all the Visual C++ 2008 Installed on my device and wrote the below code but I am stuck. Code Executes but no action takes place. Please Assist.

```
$log      = "C:\VC2008.log"
$regkey = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Select-Object DisplayName)
$RegKey.PSObject.Properties |  ForEach-Object {
    If($_.Name -like '*DisplayName*')
    {
        If ($_.value -like 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2008')
        {
            "$date [INFO]`t $regkey.PSChildname found in Registry !!! " | Out-File $log -append
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `Get-ItemProperty`? You're trying to retrieve keys, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're retrieving your values incorrectly and over-complicating things.

### Working solution:

```
$Log    = 'C:\VC2008.log'
$RegKey = Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
     Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like '*Microsoft Visual C++ 2008*' }
If ($RegKey)
{
    "$(Get-Date) [INFO]`t $($RegKey.PSChildName) found in registry!" |
        Out-File -FilePath $Log -Append
}
```

### Output:

> 12/20/2017 11:12:51 AM [INFO]  {8220EEFE-38CD-377E-8595-13398D740ACE} found in registry!

### Test key:

```
AuthorizedCDFPrefix :
Comments            :
Contact             :
DisplayVersion      : 9.0.30729
HelpLink            :
HelpTelephone       :
InstallDate         : 20170901
InstallLocation     :
InstallSource       : c:\14a5eb4f904aafee464a2e0ecc\
ModifyPath          : MsiExec.exe /X{8220EEFE-38CD-377E-8595-13398D740ACE}
NoModify            : 1
NoRepair            : 1
Publisher           : Microsoft Corporation
Readme              :
Size                :
EstimatedSize       : 1136
UninstallString     : MsiExec.exe /X{8220EEFE-38CD-377E-8595-13398D740ACE}
URLInfoAbout        :
URLUpdateInfo       :
VersionMajor        : 9
VersionMinor        : 0
WindowsInstaller    : 1
Version             : 151025673
Language            : 1033
DisplayName         : Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 9.0.30729.17
sEstimatedSize2     : 13596
PSPath              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{8220EEFE-38CD-377E-8595-13398D740ACE}
PSParentPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
PSChildName         : {8220EEFE-38CD-377E-8595-13398D740ACE}
PSProvider          : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. This is exactly what I wanted. I made a slight change in the line  If ($Prop.DisplayName -like '*Microsoft Visual C++ 2008*')

Comment: @ArunAshokan Great, if my solution solved your problem, kindly mark it as the answer with the checkmark under the vote count.  If you make that change, it won't work anymore, however. `-like` works due to wildcards, if you don't use wildcards, you should be using `-eq`

Comment: @ArunAshokan Ignore my comment about the change, if you want to use code examples in comments, be sure to surround the code with a graveaccent: \` <code> \`. Otherwise they're interpreted as markdown (your stars turned the text to italics)

Answer (score 1):

This should get you the Value you want:

```
    (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* ).displayname | Where-object{$_ -like 'Microsoft visual c++ 2008*'}
```